# How to update resources after CustomResourceDefinitions changes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I'm new to Kubernetes. Got confused with how CustomResourceDefinations changes got to apply:-)
Ex: If I have a CustomResourceDefinations "Prometheus", it creates a Statefulsets which create one pod. After the CRD changed, I need to use the latest CRD to create my pod again. What is the correct way? Should I completely remove the Statefulsets and pod then recreate them or just simply do "kubectl delete pod" then the change will auto apply when the new pod gets created? Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator, or more specifically the custom controller at the heart of the operator, takes care of this. It watches for changes in the Kubernetes API and updates things as needed to respond.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean after the controller sync the CRD, I just need to delete the Statefulsets and it should take the changes? I tried that but it still not change...In my case it might be something specific related to Prometheus-operator prevent the change...

Comment: Confirmed for my case is Prometheus-operator prevent the reload.

Comment: Without seeing your specific case, it should be updating everything automatically. No deletes needed. If you need specific support, there is a `#prometheus-operator` channel in Kubernetes slack.