# Upgrading Controller after upgrading a CustomResourceDefinition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

With Kubernetes 1.22, the beta API for the `CustomResourceDefinition` `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1` was removed and replaced with `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1`. While changing the CRDs, I have come to realize that my older controller (operator pattern, originally written for `v1alpha1`) still tries to list `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1alpha1` even though I have changed the CRD to `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1`.

I have read [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58481850/no-matches-for-kind-deployment-in-version-extensions-v1beta1) and it states that for deployment, I should change the API version but my case is an extension of this since I don't have the controller for the new API.

Do I need to write a new controller for the new API version?

Comment: did you see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778620/how-to-update-resources-after-customresourcedefinitions-changes)?

Comment: That question is similar but there is a small difference. In that question the operator is not custom, we have written the operator in house. As such if I change the API version, I am not sure if the controller can manage the new API version. Even after changing the API version of the CRD to v1 from v1Alpha1, I get an error message stating that tha controller is trying to list CRD with API version v1alpha1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to write a new controller for the new API version ?

Unfortunately, it looks like it does. If you are unable to apply what is described in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778620/how-to-update-resources-after-customresourcedefinitions-changes), because you are using a custom controller then you need to create your own new controller (if you cannot change API inside it) that will work with the supported API. Look at [Custom controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#custom-controllers) page in the official documentation.

> I am not sure if the controller can manage the new API version. Even after changing the API version of the CRD to v1 from v1Alpha1, I get an error message stating that tha controller is trying to list CRD with API version v1alpha1.

It looks like the controller has some bugs. There should be no problem referencing the new API as written [in this documentation](It looks like the controller is badly written. There should be no problem referencing the new API as written in this documentation.):

> The  **v1.22**  release will stop serving the following deprecated API versions in favor of newer and more stable API versions:
>
> - Ingress in the  **extensions/v1beta1**  API version will no longer be served
> - Migrate to use the  **networking.k8s.io/v1beta1**  API version, available since v1.14. >Existing persisted data can be retrieved/updated via the new version.

> Kubernetes 1.16 is due to be released in September 2019, so be sure to audit your configuration and integrations now!
>
> - Change YAML files to reference the newer APIs
> - **Update custom integrations and controllers to call the newer APIs**
> - Update third party tools (ingress controllers, continuous delivery systems) to call the newer APIs

See also [Kubernetes API and Feature Removals In 1.22: Here’s What You Need To Know](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/).